# Create msi installer using visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I tried to create a MSI installer for a simple windows project with basic set up. When I ran the built msi file it is not installing anything in the target location neither creating a desktop icon. Though I can find an entry in control panel. I am using VS 2013, not able to understand why it is not creating anything.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should say what you actually did. It won't install anything to the target system unless you put files (or project output) in the Application Folder in the setup project, and it won't create a desktop shortcut unless you right-click the executable in the Application Folder view, create shortcut, then drag and drop the shortcut to the Desktop folder, again this is in the setup project's File System view.

Start here, old but still they way they work:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/